# iOS - Get notification when Bluetooth device is disconnected

Tags: objective-c, ios, bluetooth

Is there a way to get notified when a Bluetooth device is disconnected from the iPhone?

We have tried with a car-handsfree "Parrot v5.11C" and a iMac Wireless Keyboard. Both devices are recognized by the native Bluetooth of the iPhone, but using the CoreBluetooth Framework and the CBCentralManager, we do not get any peripheral devices list. We just want to get notified when an specific device (selected by the user) is disconnected.

We think that the devices we have tried are not BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) compatible, so the CoreBluetooth Framework cannot find them.

**Is there any alternative to list the nearby devices, select one and get notified when it gets disconnected?**

Answer (score -1):

You have to know if you want to use Bluetooth Low Energy (CoreBluetooth.framework) or "classical" Bluetooth (ExternalAccessory.framework).
I believe that your accessory are not BLE capable, only Bluetooth.
If you check the samples of Apple EADemo, check out this line:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_accessoryDidDisconnect:) name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
```

Play with this sample to get more informations and this *NSNotificationCenter*.

Comment: I connected bluetooth headset, but ExternalAccessory returns empty list on connectedAccessories

Comment: Headset is a particular BluetoothProfile that might not appear in ExternalAccessory except if the headset have another one compliant with the EAframework. See this: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647